Symfony 6: How to specify user provider for custom authenticator
I have a couple of user providers and I'd like to use only one authenticator in security.yaml:
    providers:
        admin_users_token_provider:
            entity: { class: App\Entity\Admin, property: loginToken }
        customer_users_token_provider:
            entity: { class: App\Entity\Customer, property: loginToken }

    firewalls:
        admin_token:
            pattern: ^/admin/\w\w/login-by-token/
            provider: admin_users_token_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\Authenticators\TokenAuthenticator
            context: admin
        customer_token:
            pattern: ^/\w\w/login-by-token/
            provider: customer_users_token_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\Authenticators\TokenAuthenticator
            context: customer


I tried to get access to the admin provider in the custom Authenticator because I'm trying POST /admin/en/login-by-token/:
class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
    const LOGIN_TOKEN_ROUTE_PARAM = 'loginToken';

    public function __construct(
        protected UserProviderInterface $userProvider
    ) {
        //
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->get(self::LOGIN_TOKEN_ROUTE_PARAM) !== null;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $token = $request->get(self::LOGIN_TOKEN_ROUTE_PARAM);

        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByIdentifier($token);
        /** @noinspection PhpPossiblePolymorphicInvocationInspection */
        if (!$user->isActive() || $user->isDeleted()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge(
                $token,
                [$this->userProvider, 'loadUserByIdentifier']
        ));
    }
}

I expected to get admin_users_token_provider in constructor of the authenticator but I get the customer provider.
How to ensure the proper user provider is passed to the authenticator?

The only solution I found was to wire both providers to the authenticator and to try them both to use consequently.
services.yaml
    App\Security\Authenticators\TokenAuthenticator:
        arguments:
            $customerProvider: '@security.user.provider.concrete.customer_users_token_login'
            $adminProvider: '@security.user.provider.concrete.admin_users_token_login'

TokenAuthenticator.php
class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
    const LOGIN_TOKEN_ROUTE_PARAM = 'loginToken';

    public function __construct(
        protected UserProviderInterface $customerProvider,
        protected UserProviderInterface $adminProvider
    ) {

    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return $request->get(self::LOGIN_TOKEN_ROUTE_PARAM) !== null;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $token = $request->get(self::LOGIN_TOKEN_ROUTE_PARAM);

        $userProvider = $this->customerProvider;
        $user = null;
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByIdentifier($token);
        } catch (Exception) {
        }
        if (!$user || !$user->isActive() || $user->isDeleted()) {
            $userProvider = $this->adminProvider;
            try {
                $user = $userProvider->loadUserByIdentifier($token);
            } catch (Exception) {
            }
            if (!$user || !$user->isActive() || $user->isDeleted()) {
                throw new UserNotFoundException();
            }
        }

        return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($token, [$userProvider, 'loadUserByIdentifier']));
    }
}

